# How to use multiple apps in a single app? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i want an application with different other application like, Skype, Safari, iBooks etc embed.  I am able to use Skype and Safari using buttons, but when i launch skype or safari the main application on which i am launching these applications closes. I want these applications to open in main applications view itself.
Main Application- is Custom application used to launch skype or safari

any Method? any suggestions to proceed? any apis? any tutorials? Thanks!!

Comment: you cant open several 'apps' at once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. All you can do is to use the public available APIs of each of these "apps" and create your own app flow using them. But you will have to do most things on your own.